# Multiple hypothesis testing Beherens-Fisher problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

The question is about a very basic problem in first statistical classes.

I have two independent sample, $X = \{x_{i}\}_{i = 1}^{N_1}$ and $Y = \{y_{i}\}_{i = 1}^{N_2}$ each coming from a gaussian population: $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \sigma^2_x)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_y, \sigma^2_y)$. Both samples have small size.

I want to test at the 5% significance level whether they have equal mean $\mu_x = \mu_y$ .

I know that: $\bar{X} - \bar{Y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x - \mu_y, \sigma^2_x / N_1 + \sigma^2_y/N_2)$

But the population parameters are of course unknown. I know that if the samples are both small and  population variances are unknown but different, there is no solution, is the so called Beherens-Fisher problem (see F. Samaniego "stochastic modeling and mathematical statistics" pag.432). But if the population variances are equal then it holds that:

$ t = \frac{\bar{X} - \bar{Y} }{\sqrt{s^2(1/N_1 + 1/N_2)}} \sim t_{N_1 + N_2 - 2} $    where    $s = \frac{(N_1 - 1)s_1^2 + (N_2 - 1)s_2^2}{N_1 + N_2 - 2}$ and $s_i^2$ is the usual unbiased estimator for the variance.

So I think that to solve the original problem I should first test whether $\sigma^2_x = \sigma^2_y$ and then proceed by using the t just defined.

The problem is: how should I take the significance level in the two test? Is it correct to pose the problem in the context of multiple hypothesis testing and, if so, if and how should I take into account that the second test distribution depends on whether "I accept" the first?

They're sequential, or, I would say, the t test is conditional on the F test for the variance...

Comment: One simple method could be to apply Bonferroni.

Comment: I edited the question, I know Bonferroni is rather really about when should one has a multiple hp testing framework and how to face the case in which the distribution depends on the firs part

Comment: Yes, acknowledging the multiplicity issue here would be the most honest choice. The t-test doesn't really depend on the F-test, it's you that are imposing such a dependence. However, in such problems, a permutation t-test fills the bill without requiring you to know the group variances.

Comment: ok thank you. But could you explain slightly better/longer what does it mean that I introduce the dependence, becouse is really about how do one state dependence among different tests... And eventually, if you could make the argument "rigorous", could you post it as answer?

Comment: I seem to recall a paper or two on this and related issues in *The American Statistician*, maybe in the 70s or 80s.